# Accessing and overwriting Multiindex df data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I'm trying to multiply all the values of the following multiindex df for which the first multiindex equals Property_2 with a scalar:

```
(index_1,index_2)    Col1
Property_1     A      1
               B      2
               C      3
Property_2     D      1
               E      2
               F      3
```

I've tried various ways:

```
df.loc[Property_2,:] = df.loc[Property_2,:]*0.01
df.loc[(Property_2,:),:] = df.loc[(Property_2,:),:]*0.01
```

but I am getting back nan's in the relevant places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the indices don't match. One way to get around the issue is to assign the underlying numpy array:

```
df.loc['Property_2', 'Col1'] = df.loc['Property_2', 'Col1'].mul(0.01).to_numpy()
```

or you could use `mask`:

```
df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].mask(df.index.get_level_values(0) == 'Property_2', df['Col1']*0.01)
```

Output:

```
                    Col1
index_1    index_2      
Property_1 A        1.00
           B        2.00
           C        3.00
Property_2 D        0.01
           E        0.02
           F        0.03
```